# How to annotate any non-zero value in an Excel formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I am trying to do an average-if function and I want to average any value not equal to zero, positive *and* negative.

I have tried using a standard 'average-if' with my criteria as `"!=0"`. Full formula `=AVERAGEIF(E3:E34,"!=0",E3:E34)`

I have tried using an average-ifs with my criteria being `">0"` and `"<0"`. Full formula `=AVERAGEIFS(E3:E34, E3:E34, ">0", E3:E34, "<0")`

**What is the correct way to get the formula to operate on all non-zero values?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=AVERAGEIF(E3:E4,"<>" & 0,E3:E4)
```

Comment: You can include the zero in the comparison string. You only need the concatenation if you refer to a cell. Compare `=AVERAGEIF(E3:E4,"<>0",E3:E4)` with `=AVERAGEIF(E3:E4,"<>" & A1,E3:E4)`, where A1 has the 0.